# Derivation and character space

Tags: operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a Banach algebra and $D:A\to {A^*}$ a bounded derivation. Is it possible to define some characters on $A$ by using $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not. Take your favourite Banach algebra without characters (such as bounded operators on $\ell_p$) and consider inner derivations into the dual.

Comment: thank you, my silly mistake.